# how do i 301 Redirect to home page?

Tags: c#, web-config

i want to redirect one of my pages in my website to home page with using Web.config. I used this but it does not work.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="URL1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="http://www.mywebsite.com/unnecessary-page" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mywebsite.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Still couldn't find an answer

Answer (score 0):

There is two type of problems might you have:

1. You need to install [rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) if you have 500 error.
2. You should not use domain in your URL.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="URL1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="unnecessary-page" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I have tested this code and it works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer but this code didn't work for me. My website ends like this "website.org.tr" so not .com. Can it be related with this situation?

Comment: Do you have two binding and want to set rule only for one of them?